# How can I parse a cell array of date strings with irregular lengths in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, matlab, string-length

I have a cell array of dates as strings (format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'), where the string length varies by cell entry from 8 to 10, depending on the date (e.g., n = 8 for '1/1/2015' and n = 10 for '10/10/2015'). I want to convert each cell array entry to its corresponding double as a datenum quantity. I've tried:

```
id = find(~cellfun( @isempty, regexp( dateList, '/', 'tokenExtents' ) ) );
```

and

```
id = find(~cellfun( @isempty, strfind( dateList, '/' ) ) );
```

but this isn't right. A snippet of the cell array is provided:

```
dateList = {'9/9/2016';
            '9/10/2016';
            '10/10/2016';
            '10/11/2016'};
```

Comment: You may have a specific reason for using `datenum`, but if not, then you should move towards using the more modern `datetime` functionality.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to use is [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), since it will accept a cell array of strings:

```
dateList = {'9/9/2016'; '9/10/2016'; '10/10/2016'; '10/11/2016'};
id = datenum(dateList);
```

And to confirm it worked:

```
>> datestr(id)

ans =

09-Sep-2016
10-Sep-2016
10-Oct-2016
11-Oct-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Extract each cell to 3 different blocks with [strsplit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html): day,month and year

2) Use [pad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pad.html) to make each block the same length (2 for day and month and 4 for year)

3) Join the string together with [D,'/',M,'/',Y] and you are able to run datenum without problem.

Edit 1: I think the other answer is far more easy, I didn't know datenum can take strings with slightly different foramt.

Comment: Thanks.  The first reply works just fine; I was making it too hard, but I didn't know that datenum could accept a cell array of strings.