# How can I convert a cell array to a datetime in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of type cell.

In each cell is a date, written as 'Mmm-yyyy'. For example, 'Apr-1997' and 'Oct-2002'.

How can I turn the cell array into datetime format, and then sort the dataframe on this date column.

Comment: `datetime` accepts cell arrays as input. Where are you having difficulty? Please add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: What's a "dataframe" in this context, since it's not a built-in MATLAB variable type? Is it a table? A cell? What's your desired output variable type? Without details on your specific issue it looks like there are existing questions on this topic e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47162581/3978545)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "`dataframe`" you mean a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html):

```
t = table; % example table
t.datestring = {'Apr-1997'; 'Oct-2002'; 'Jan-2000'};
t.other = [10; 20; 30];
```

This creates an example table:

```
t =
  3×2 table
    datestring    other
    __________    _____
    'Apr-1997'    10   
    'Oct-2002'    20   
    'Jan-2000'    30
```

To create a new column with content of type [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) and sort rows based on that:

```
t.date = datetime(t.datestring); % create new column
[~, ind] = sort(datetime(t.date)); % get index based on sorting that column
t_new = t(ind, :); % apply that index to the rows
```

This gives

```
t_new =
  3×3 table
    datestring    other       date    
    __________    _____    ___________
    'Apr-1997'    10       01-Apr-1997
    'Jan-2000'    30       01-Jan-2000
    'Oct-2002'    20       01-Oct-2002
```